# I want to load text string from an external file into my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm wondering if there's a way to load text string into my htaccess file. I don't want to manually type it in the file.
Here's what I already have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteBase /file_name.txt/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gwcgroup\.co.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gwcgroup\.co.uk$
RewriteRule .* https://gwcgroup.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gwcgroup\.co.uk$
RewriteRule .* https://gwcgroup.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess file. `I'm wondering if there's a way to load text string into my htaccess file.` could you please do elaborate more on this statement? Thank you.

Comment: An ".htaccess" file is a configuration file. It is not meant to be active itself in any way. You certainly could use some form of preprocessor to _create_ a ".htaccess" file in a dynamic manner based on some template which you compile.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I was thinking if I could read a text file with the string into that line. Actually, that link is where I have my folder name. But I don't want to directly type it in

Answer (score 1):

This feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

(Warning... lots of "however"s follow...)

Yes, you can read a text file into a `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite and an Apache expression (Apache 2.4). However, you can't read it directly into the `RewriteBase` directive as you are implying. However, you can read the file and store it in an environment variable and effectively use it in order to *simulate* what the `RewriteBase` directive does.

However, in the `.htaccess` file you've posted you are only making use of `RewriteBase` in the very last rule (on the very last line). So, you only need to target that one rule (no need for an environment variable).

However, there are other ways to effectively calculate the `RewriteBase` (or rather calculate the root URL-path and store this in an env var), depending on what you are trying to do. So, you may not need to do this at all.

There are other errors/inconsistencies in the file you posted that also make me question whether this is really what you should be doing.

Anyway, focusing on the last rule (which is the only place in your file that `RewriteBase` applies)....

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
> ```

To read from the external file `file_name.txt` (in the document root) and use the contents of this file as the base URL-path in the *substitution* string in the last `RewriteRule` directive then you could do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond expr "file('%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/file_name.txt') =~ m#^(/.*)#"
RewriteRule (.*) %1index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The `%1` backreference (to the capturing group in the preceding *CondPattern*) holds the contents of the first line of the text file (since the dot does not match newlines). Although, this regex is rather generic (it matches *everything* after an initial slash - to the end of the line) - you may want to make this more restrictive, to ensure that it only matches a valid URL-path you are expecting.

If `file_name.txt` does not exist (or cannot be read) then a non-fatal rewrite:error occurs (check your error log) and the rule simply fails.

And `file_name.txt` contains a single line of the form:

```
/path/to/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. I found a solution. I stored my script in a variable and dynamically create and update the htaccess file each time I need to.
Here's my working code

```
$htaccess = fopen("./.htaccess", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($htaccess, $ht_input);
        fclose($htaccess);
```

Comment: This looks like php code ... Keep in mind that if your http server processes this code such approach _might_ bring huge security issues... In general a software should _never_ be able to modify itself from a security point of view. I know, that rule is often violated, most easy to use web applications violate it and software installation under MS Windows systems also has this issue. But still that rule is worth considering ...